# Error during 'npm install dev' in Visual Studio Code running on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, laravel, visual-studio-code

I am learning laravel and when I tried to run npm install dev in integrated terminal of VS Code, it shows error.

Versions I am using.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Q8sa.jpg)

Console:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3sJs.jpg)

Log file report: `0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev' ]
2 info using npm@5.5.1
3 info using node@v9.3.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle @~predev: @
6 info lifecycle @~dev: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~dev: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Avishek\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\Avishek\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Avishek\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Avishek\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle @~dev: CWD: C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp
10 silly lifecycle @~dev: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run development' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~dev: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: @ dev:`npm run development
`13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:280:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:159:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v9.3.0
19 verbose npm  v5.5.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error @ dev:`npm run development
`22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the @ dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2, true ]`

package.json contents: 
`{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.17",
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "vue": "^2.5.7"
    }
}`

Comment: What is the content of package.json file?

Comment: I have updated that in the question. @NikolaAndreev

Answer (score 0):

just do `npm install` if the issue persist try to add `--ignore-platform-reqs`

Answer (score 0):

The command must be `npm install --dev`, you just missed the 2 dashes.